# SQL Server Spatial Indexes Setup

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, spatial-index

I currently have two tables cities and listings, both have a field called Position and that is a spatial field.
**My question is have i set up my indexes correctly or should I add/remove some?**
For cities I do not show them on a map, I only use one query that is relevant to cities and that is i take a lat/long and i get the 50 nearest cities and for listings I do the nearest as well and I show them on a map like I do here

http://tinyurl.com/on9454y

For both tables I have 2 indexes each that are set as follow.

256 HHHH

```
/****** Object:  Index [Position_Index]    Script Date: 1/25/2015 3:56:50 PM ******/
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [Position_Index] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
[Position]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 256, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

16 HHHH

```
/****** Object:  Index [Spatial_Index]    Script Date: 1/25/2015 3:58:23 PM ******/
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [Spatial_Index] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
[Position]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH),    
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

using sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one of the indices for the Position field in each table.  Having 2 is redundant and will harm performance from the standpoint that any database writes to those fields would have to update both.  You do require having the index in both tables, since you are looking for nearest points in both cities and listings.

In terms of which one to start with, it depends on whether or not you are using points or areas.

For areas (i.e. not just points), you should start with the 16 cells per object one since according to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712(v=sql.105).aspx)

> By default, the cells-per-object limit is 16 cells per object, which
>   provides a satisfactory trade-off between space and precision for most
>   spatial indexes.

I would apply this to the cities and see how your query performs.  If not satisfactory, increase it (probably just keep doubling) until you see no performance gain.  I imagine 16 should work just fine for you for the reason stated above, but it will be very data specific.  Again, it will only matter if you are not using points.

If your data only contains points (which seems probable in your situation, at least for listings), then the CPO value is not important, and you should get very good performance by setting each level to HIGH as you have already done.  From the article [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9694.tuning-spatial-point-data-queries-in-sql-server-2012.aspx):

> In the case of point data, it has been found in most, if not in all,
>   cases that spatial indexes with all grid levels set to HIGH outperform
>   other configurations.  Since we are dealing with point data, the
>   CELLS_PER_OBJECT setting is irrelevant and can be set to any legal
>   value (1-8192) without effect.

### References

I would highly recommend reading these articles if you have not already done so:

- [Technet starting point](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [More advanced/useful Technet wiki article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9694.tuning-spatial-point-data-queries-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)
- [boomphisto blog](http://boomphisto.blogspot.com/2011/04/black-art-of-spatial-index-tuning-in.html)

Comment: What do you need to know about the data itself, I can provide more info to get a more accurate answer

Comment: Some data that could help:  (1) Approximately how many cities and how often you add additional ones?  Same for listings.  (2) Are your geo columns just points or more complex areas?  (3) How often is this data being queired?  (4) How big is the area you plan to cover?  World?  One county?  Somewhere in between?

Comment: I have 2 areas (2 sites), 1 covers the world with approximately 145k cities and 900k listings and new ones are never added, this list is very static and maybe get updated once a year.  2. I cover canada and cities and new listings are added dailty, sometimes once city is added with 1k listings, someetimes a couple of cities

Comment: @Madision did you get the bounty? i forgot to set it, if not let me know what to do to make sure you get it

Comment: I did not since it expired, but no big deal.  Just hope this works out for you.

Comment: How can i raise this with mods so you do get it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95039/what-happens-when-bounty-gets-expired

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Madison has said.
Though I would add that I find most queries require a hint to use the spatial index, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM geoTable WITH (INDEX (spatial_index))
WHERE geoColumn.STDistance(@g) < 100
```

Remember though if you are doing a number of joins and/or where clauses using the spatial index may not actually be any quicker than scanning, so test both scenarios for different cases.

If your tables are fairly big (1 million + rows) spatial indexes tend to slow. Consider spliting them in seperate tables, either per state or country as you cannot partition these indexes.